# Why is a day added when converting XMLGregorianCalender to Date here?

Tags: java, date, datetime, type-conversion

OK firstly I line in New Zealand so our date is written yyyy/MM/dd.

Now here when I convert a date from the server (I've just coppied the XML string for clarity) a day is added to the days and the time becomes 9am instead of 9pm.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCalander = null;

    try {
        xmlCalander = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2014-07-20T21:00:00Z");
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Today at9pm converted: " + simpleDateFormat.format(xmlCalander.toGregorianCalendar().getTime()));
}
```

The output is:

> Today at9pm converted: 2014-07-21T09:00:00

When I'm expecting (24 hr time):

> Today at9pm converted: 2014-07-20T21:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Z` from date string and it should work.

Comment: Cheers, that worked great. But why is that? And if I don't have access to the string and just call `object.getDate()` and convert that, then how do I get an accurate result?